# How to find out the Type that a dependency is being supplied to in StructureMap?

Tags: inversion-of-control, structuremap, nlog

I have a class whose constructor looks like

```
public class Foo(NLog.Logger logger)
```

I am using [StructureMap 2.6.4.1](http://docs.structuremap.net/) to do dependency injection (via constructor injection entirely, no property injection).  I am using [NLog](http://nlog-project.org) for my logging.  One of the nice features of NLog is that one can route log events to different targets via the loggers having names.  It's very flexible, therefore, to name the loggers after the owning type's fully qualified name (In the example above, it would be `<namespace>.Foo`)

Castle Windsor's logging facility will supply a logger to the instances that require them, named for the class of the owning instance.

However, I haven't been able to get StructureMap to do this.

I've tried the `EnrichWith((context, type) => {})` method, but `context.ParentType` is always null.  Here's an example of my registry:

```
public class InfrastructureRegistry : Registry
{
    public InfrastructureRegistry()
    {
        For<NLog.Logger>().Use<NLog.Logger>()
            .EnrichWith((context, pluginType) => 
                NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(context.ParentType.FullName)
            );
    }
}
```

I'm perplexed.  How do I do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ParentType` in the context yields null if the object on the top of the build stack is beeing requested, which would mean that a Logger is requested. I tried a simple scenario with a class having a ctor dependency to a `NLog.Logger` and it worked perfectly.

```
c.For<NLog.Logger>().Use(ctx => ctx.ParentType == null ? 
    NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(ctx.BuildStack.Current.ConcreteType.Name) :   
    NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(ctx.ParentType.UnderlyingSystemType.Name));
```

I had the following dependent class:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    private readonly NLog.Logger _logger;
    public Service(NLog.Logger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

which produced a `NLog.Logger` with the name *Service*.

If this doesn't work for you I think you need to produce a small repro of the problem.

By the way, you don't need `EnrichWith` unless you want to wrap the constructed instance with something else or use some data from the constructed instance.